# Efficient way of checking if a set is convex in 3 or more dimensions?

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming

Consider the following set:
$$C:=\Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}: x_3=\lvert x_2\lvert,\:x_1\leq3\Bigg\}$$
Now, I can graph this using a program, like Mathematica, and tell visually whether or not its convex. However, I was wondering how to do this without relying on such method because if we were dealing with more than 3 dimensions then it would be hard or impossible to realize at that point. What's the best method?

Answer (score 3):

The second constraint is linear.

Let's look closer to the first constraint.

$(0,1,1)$ is in $C$, $(0,-1, 1)$ is in $C$.

Consider $\frac12(0,1,1)+\frac12(0,-1,1)=(0,0,1)$ and it is not in $C$. Hence it can't be convex.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a method of solving these type of problems. Say we were dealing with 5 variables instead of 3. I'm not looking for a shortcut, just a general way of looking at these problems of higher dimensions.

Comment: I think it depends on the property on the constraint. For this example though the example is in $3$ dimension, I only use property of $2$ dimensions and understanding of absolute value.